# Oracle joining rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains this:

```
USERNAME         IP            MAC
username1    11.11.11.11
username1    22.22.22.22 
username1                    ffffffff
username1                    dddddddd
```

How can I merge these four rows into two like this:

```
USERNAME         IP            MAC
username1    11.11.11.11     ffffffff
username1    22.22.22.22     dddddddd
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post table names and structures of the tables and what have you tried?

Comment: Why not like this? I am confused

USERNAME         IP            MAC
username1    11.11.11.11     ffffffff
username1    22.22.22.22     dddddddd 
username1    11.11.11.11     dddddddd 
username1    22.22.22.22     ffffffff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation with `row_number()`.  Assuming that each row has only one value:

```
select username, max(ip), max(mac)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username
                                             (case when ip is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by coalesce(ip, mac)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by username, seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d204f12e7220b82fc9fca0ba55953da8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is close to what I need, but it merges IP 11.11.11.11 with MAC ddddddd instead of ffffffff and oposite . Would there be a way to merge it "in order"?

Comment: @BorisMamić . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering -- and hence no way to produce your results consistently -- unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.